# SQL Server 2017 Express Edition: localhost and 127.0.0.1 are not identical

Tags: windows-10, sql-server, localhost, visual-studio-2017

I need install and use SQL Server 2017 Express Edition.

I downloaded it from this link: [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2017 Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55994) and installed basic version to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server`.

I can run it and have access to `http://localhost`, but I should use `http://127.0.0.1`. And when I use http://127.0.0.1. I see the following:

```
Bad Request - Invalid Hostname
HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.
```

I tried to edit my `hosts`. I went to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`, open `hosts` and uncomment the following line: `127.0.0.1       localhost`

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
     127.0.0.1       localhost
#    ::1             localhost
```

But it has no effect. I have access to `localhost`, but hasn't on `127.0.0.1`. The bad request.

I tried a reboot.

What am I missing?

```
Windows 10 Pro 64    
Visual Studio 2017
SQL Server 2017 Express Edition 14.0.1000.169, RTM
```

[IIS screen. (Site name, URL address, Identifier)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJZgV.png)

Comment: When you configured the database did you use localhost or 127.0.0.1 normally configuration files have to be modified to allow both (i.e. Apache, MySQL, ect.)

Comment: @Ramhound I use the Visual Studio solution that has been created not by me. I just should run it in the studio, update the database and start "run without debugging". It opens the browser on localhost page. But I need use 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Ramhound And I can't find where the author of this .sln configured addresses

Comment: You are not looking in the correct place.  Look at how IIS is configured.  *The Visual Studio solution has nothing to do with this problem.*

Comment: @Ramhound IIS show's it as localhost only: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJZgV.png (Site name, URL address, Identifier)

Comment: So you have answered your own question